# Connecting Mongodb to Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I try to make a project and I need to connect mongodb to django and I have this error. I looked over all the pages about this error and I think that I did all that stuff and still didn't manage to solve it. Do you know what I need to do?

[django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDdKu.png) 'django' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Comment: Did you mean to use `djongo` as the engine? Note: It is not a typo, See: https://www.djongomapper.com/get-started/

Comment: Yes. This was the problem. Thanks a lot. A strange thing is that on cmd I have the same issue, but if I run the commands in the Visual code's terminal is all good.